# Dynamically created content in Leaflet popup using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to make a dynamically created dropdown list to submit user content from a Leaflet popup (each popup contains a different list based on condition). However, I somehow don't manage to clear the list if a popup is closed and a new one is opened. This is my code so far:

```
polygons=L.geoJson(data, {
 onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {

  layer.on('click', function (){
   var list = document.getElementById('dropdownBuild');  //create html list elements dynamically.
   var buildings = {'School': 2000, 'Hospital': 4000,'Pop-up Bar':50};
   var selText;

   for (var k in buildings){  //generate list element if condition is true
    if (buildings[k] >= feature.properties.area){
       var entry = document.createElement('li');
       entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(k));
       list.appendChild(entry);
    }
   }

   $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){ //submit user choice
    selText = $(this).text();
    var sql ="UPDATE data_game SET usage='"+selText+"' WHERE cartodb_id=22";
    submitToProxy(sql);
   });
  });

  var container = $('<div />');   //popup container
  var label = L.marker(layer.getBounds().getCenter());

  //fill popup container with list
  container.html(" <input type='hidden' name='selection' id='buildInput'> <div class='dropdown'> <button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>Build something<span class='caret'></span></button><input id='search_type' name='search_type' type='hidden'><ul class='dropdown-menu' id='dropdownBuild'></ul>" );

  layer.bindPopup(container[0]);
 }
}).addTo(map);
```

I am guessing it would have to be something like this, taking the list Id and removing all children, but I can't figure out where to put it:

```
$("#dropdownBuild").children().remove();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just a question, can I open up developer tools and submittoproxy any sql I want?

Comment: Hey, submitToProxy() is a custom function that uses $.post() and php to update the sql database

Comment: The point @BryanDellinger was making is that your code would appear to be wide open to a SQL injection attack. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @emily but you know that someone could set breakpoint and call something like `submitToProxy("DROP TABLE data_game;")`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I am quite new to this. Would this be solved if I moved the sql query to the php code?